# How To Preform A Click Action on HTML Class attribute

Tags: c#, html, class

So basically there is a made html form with a button, it doesnt have a ID, but it has Input Class. I want for C# to click the button in webbrowser when I click the button in C# form.

If it had an ID I could do that by using this: `

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("submit").InvokeMember("click");
        }
```

But how to do that if thers no id, just class?

***note: I don't have access to the html
form document.***

Comment: i think we may need some clarification.  c# is a server-side language, so it's not going to be clicking any buttons.  are you looking for a javascript solution perhaps?

Comment: no, I want that by using webbrowser within C# form to preform actions  on html elements

Comment: If you haven't gotten an answer that works, you can edit your question to add more details/clarify, or you can add a bounty (the system loans you 50 rep to sweeten the pot).  Please don't ask this again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery it's as simple as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".yourclass").click(function() {
      $("#<%=YourButton.ClientID%>").click();
   });
});
</script>
```

*YourButton* is the ID of the server side button to be clicked when the button with *yourclass* is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

If your C# code is a Silverlight app, then you can definitely do it - in fact I recently had to.

Here is a link that was helpful for me: [Communicating between JavaScript & Silverlight](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/08/tip-of-the-day-15-communicating-between-javascript-amp-silverlight.aspx)

(Check out the `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke()` method)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an asp:button to the page and then add javascript to your existing button to click this new server control on click.  Then add your c# code to the click event handler of the new button you're adding to the form.